# Best way to secure tablets + other devices in a room

Tags: security

What's the best way to secure a bunch of Android tablets and other expensive devices in a room in an educational setting? For various reasons, physically attaching them to something is unideal. Is there some sort of alarm that could be activated if the devices are taken through the door or a certain distance from the room? Any ideas?

Answer (score 3):

You might want to check with a company or vendor that specializes in either retailer displays or retailer focused security systems. You might be able to purchase a system where you attach some kind of RFID tag the back of your device which triggers an alarm if it's carried through a door.

The low tech way to accomplish this would be just having a staff member with a clipboard "checkout" each device to a student at the door and then check them back in when they leave. If you come up short on your roll call, you'll at least know which student was assigned the missing tablet.

Comment: Big fan of the low tech way of doing this. I try and keep meticulous notes, so this is second nature for me. Make a spreadsheet that has all the serial numbers, etc. on it and then print it out. Pencil in the student it was issued to and you should be good to go!

Comment: Yeah, we've talked about the low-tech solution... We want to do something cool though, because this is a first-year engineering programming lab. And we have a budget to spend on cool stuff.

Comment: @iansinke - Well I suppose that's nice but personally I'd avoid the temptation to be overly clever.

Answer (score 2):

RFID tags are your best bet for physical security like what you're asking. [This site](http://www.rfid-library.com/en/default_e.html) explains them well. The site is designed for libraries but the principle applies to your situation. There's a lot of solutions out there.